# Exporting Plesk customer data to a document possible?

Tags: sql, email, cpanel, plesk

**Background**:
First off I'm using plesk 11.5 which I'm planning to migrate to plesk 12 and a new server.
I have a lot of domains on old an server, plenty of subscriptions and customers.

**What I want to do:**
I need to send an e-mail to every customer that we will migrate them.

**My question:**
Is there a way for me to export customer data via panel like CPanel can?

You know, so i can get a nice spreadsheet with customer name, subscriptions, his e-mail etc..

Can i do that via databases maybe? How would that query look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can find out this info from plesk databases. Please try with following one of the sql query and change it with your info which you want.

```
select concat(mail.mail_name,"@",domains.name) as address, mail.account_id from mail,domains,accounts where mail.dom_id=domains.id and mail.account_id=accounts.id order by address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> Tools & Settings > Mass Email Messages

?

It's not meet your requirements?

Comment: That is actually not bad. Cant believe i missed that in panel.
Ty for your answer.

Comment: Well, yes tools UI composition is quite difficult.